# How to prevent user billing info update on checkout?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I need to prevent WooCommerce from updating user's billing address information from checkout billing form. I want to let users update their billing info only from their account settings.

Is there a way to achieve this? Maybe a filter?

Comment: could this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36260531/woocommerce-readonly-billing-fields ?

Comment: See this also: https://www.wpmayor.com/how-to-remove-the-billing-details-from-woocommerce-checkout

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't fit me because what I'm actually doing is submitting a custom billing address form which activates when user wants to use alternative billing information which should not be stored anywhere. The problem is that if the user submits this form then all his billing address info stored in his account is being overridden.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the solution:

`add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_customer_data', '__return_false' );`

I hope someone will find this helpful as well!