# Woocommerce Readonly Billing Fields - Select and Radio Fields

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, custom-fields

I've implemented the solution suggested by [@zipkundan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36260531/woocommerce-readonly-billing-fields) like this:

```
    add_action('woocommerce_checkout_fields','customization_readonly_billing_fields',10,1);
function customization_readonly_billing_fields($checkout_fields){
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();;
    $user_id = $current_user->ID;
    foreach ( $checkout_fields['billing'] as $key => $field ){
        if($key == 'billing_address_1' || $key == 'billing_address_2' || $key == 'billing_first_name' || $key == 'billing_check_business' || $key == 'billing_company_name' || $key == 'billing_last_name' || $key == 'billing_codice_fiscale' || $key == 'billing_vat' || $key == 'billing_address_1' || $key == 'billing_city' || $key == 'billing_state' || $key == 'billing_postcode' || $key == 'billing_phone' || $key == 'billing_email'){
            $key_value = get_user_meta($user_id, $key, true);
            if( strlen($key_value)>0){
                $checkout_fields['billing'][$key]['custom_attributes'] = array('readonly'=>'readonly');
            }
        }
    }
    return $checkout_fields;
}
```

and it works correctly except for billing_state and for billing_check_business. billing_state is a select field billing_check_business is a rado field. Any suggestion on how to make this code working also for select and radio? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('woocommerce_billing_fields', 'my_woocommerce_billing_fields');
function my_woocommerce_billing_fields($fields)
{
    $fields['billing_first_name']['custom_attributes'] = array('readonly'=>'readonly');
    $fields['billing_last_name']['custom_attributes'] = array('readonly'=>'readonly');
    $fields['billing_address_1']['custom_attributes'] = array('readonly'=>'readonly');
    $fields['billing_address_2']['custom_attributes'] = array('readonly'=>'readonly');
    $fields['billing_postcode']['custom_attributes'] = array('readonly'=>'readonly');
    $fields['billing_city']['custom_attributes'] = array('readonly'=>'readonly');

    return $fields;
}
```